# SQL multiple calculation to be in sequence + roundup value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm need to update a table with calculation in sequence to get the correct final result.
But i think when i execute the below statement it runs all the calculation at the same time, causing the result calculated wrongly. What i need is to get something like this:

Daily X O.F = Order

Then next

Daily X ( O.F + MCT + Transit + Safety) / Container Size = No. of Kanban Card

(*Roundup the result of "No. of Kanban Card" for example 3.0 become 4*)

Then next

O.F X Daily / Container Size = Run Line

(*Roundup the result of "Run Line" for example 3.0 become 4*)

Then next

Run Line X Container Size = Lot Size

Then next

No. Of KanBan Card X Container Size = Max Inventory

Then next

(No. Of KanBan Card - Run Line) X Container Size = Trigger 1

Then next

(No. Of KanBan Card - Run Line - 1)  X Container Size = Trigger 2

Then next

(No. Of KanBan Card - Run Line - 2)  X Container Size = Trigger 3

Last

Daily X (0.5 X (O.F + MCT) + Transit + Safety) = Avg Inventory

```
SELECT [Part Num], Daily, [O.F], [Order], MCT, Transit, [Safety], [Container Size], [No. of Kanban Card], [Run Line], [Lot Size], [Max. Inventory], [Trigger 1], [Trigger 2], [Trigger 3], [Avg. Inventory],
(Daily * [O.F]) AS [Order],
(Daily * ([O.F] + MCT + Transit + [Safety]) / [Container Size]) AS [No. of Kanban Card],
([O.F] * Daily / [Container Size]) AS [Run Line],
([Run Line] * [Container Size]) AS [Lot Size],
([No. of Kanban Card] * [Container Size]) AS [Max. Inventory],
(([No. of Kanban Card] - [Run Line]) * [Container Size]) AS [Trigger 1],
(([No. of Kanban Card] - [Run Line] - 1) * [Container Size]) AS [Trigger 2],
(([No. of Kanban Card] - [Run Line] - 2) * [Container Size]) AS [Trigger 3],
(Daily * (0.5 * ([O.F] + MCT) + Transit + [Safety])) AS [Avg. Inventory]
FROM SuperMarketTest
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could select each calculation as a subquery (or more readably as a common table expression), and then base the next calculation on the subquery or previous CTE.

The other option, which might be easier is just do all your calculations as multiple update statements, one after the other.

Here's an example of the CTEs in turn...

```
;WITH c1 AS (
SELECT 
  [Part Num], 
  Daily, 
  [O.F], 
  [Order], 
  MCT, 
  Transit, 
  [Safety], 
  [Container Size], 
  [No. of Kanban Card], 
  [Run Line], 
  [Lot Size], 
  [Max. Inventory], 
  [Trigger 1], 
  [Trigger 2], 
  [Trigger 3], 
  [Avg. Inventory]
FROM SuperMarketTest
), c2 AS
(
SELECT 
  [Part Num], 
  Daily, 
  [O.F], 
  (Daily * [O.F]) AS [Order], 
  MCT, 
  Transit, 
  [Safety], 
  [Container Size], 
  (Daily * ([O.F] + MCT + Transit + [Safety]) / [Container Size]) AS [No. of Kanban Card], 
  [Run Line], 
  [Lot Size], 
  [Max. Inventory], 
  [Trigger 1], 
  [Trigger 2], 
  [Trigger 3], 
  [Avg. Inventory]
FROM c1
) , c3 AS
(
SELECT 
  [Part Num], 
  Daily, 
  [O.F], 
  [Order], 
  MCT, 
  Transit, 
  [Safety], 
  [Container Size], 
  [No. of Kanban Card], 
  ([O.F] * Daily / [Container Size]) AS [Run Line], 
  [Lot Size], 
  ([No. of Kanban Card] * [Container Size]) AS [Max. Inventory] 
  [Trigger 1], 
  [Trigger 2], 
  [Trigger 3], 
  [Avg. Inventory]
FROM c2
)
SELECT
  [Part Num], 
  Daily, 
  [O.F], 
  [Order], 
  MCT, 
  Transit, 
  [Safety], 
  [Container Size], 
  [No. of Kanban Card], 
  [Run Line], 
  [Lot Size], 
  [Max. Inventory] 
  (([No. of Kanban Card] - [Run Line]) * [Container Size]) AS [Trigger 1],
  (([No. of Kanban Card] - [Run Line] - 1) * [Container Size]) AS [Trigger 2],
  (([No. of Kanban Card] - [Run Line] - 2) * [Container Size]) AS [Trigger 3],
  (Daily * (0.5 * ([O.F] + MCT) + Transit + [Safety])) AS [Avg. Inventory]
FROM c3
```